# Application of Differentiation using Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem

Tags: measure-theory, derivatives, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I am working through old Measure Theory homework assignments and this question is giving me some trouble. It states:

Let {$f_n$} be a sequence of continuous and differentiable functions on the interval $[a,b]$. Assume that for each $t$ in $[a,b]$, $\sum_{n}|f_n(t)|$ is convergent and $|f^{'}_n(t)|\le g(n)$ where $\sum_{n}g(n)$ is convergent.  Show that the function $F(t)=\sum_{n}f_n(t)$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$ and $F'(t)=\sum_{n}f^{'}_{n}(t)$.

I know this is an application of the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem but cannot figure out how to set it up. Any hints, helps, or leads would be nice! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd start by writing
$$
f_n(t) =f_n(a)+\int_a^t f_n'(s)\,ds
$$
for $t\in[a,b]$ and $n\ge 1$.  Now sum with respect to $n$ on both sides. The Weierstrass $M$-test should come in handy to show that $\sum_n f'_n(s)$ converges *uniformly* and that the sum, call it $h(s)$, is a continuous function of $s$.

Comment: That makes sense! I do have a quick question. If we take $\sum_{n}\int_{a}^{t}f^{'}_{n}(s)ds$ then don't we need that $f^{'}_{n}\in L^{+}$ in order to switch the summation with the integral and use the Weierstrass M test? How do we know we can make that switch?

Comment: $f_n'$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, hence integrable both in the RIemann and the Lebesgue senses. To justify the switch of summation and integration, the uniform convergence of $\sum_nf'_n$ is sufficient.

Comment: Oh right. Okay that makes perfect sense. Thanks so much!